# checking column of the pyspark dataframe columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to check each column of the pyspark dataframe and if the column meets specific dtypes then it will perform certain functions. below is my codes and dataset.

dataset:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('Word Count').config('spark.some.config.option', 'some-value').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('A',1),
        ('A', 2),
        ('A',3),
        ('A', 4),
        ('B',5),
        ('B', 6),
        ('B',7),
        ('B', 8),
    ],
    ['id', 'v']
) #I save this to csv so can just ignore my read csv park below.
```

Codes:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.load('test.csv',
                         format ='com.databricks.spark.csv',
                         header='true',
                         inferSchema='true')

from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import numpy as np

i = (reduce(lambda x, y: x.withColumn(y, np.where(col(y).dtypes != 'str', col(y)+2, col(y))), df.columns, df)) # this is the part that I wanted to change.
```

Side learning request: If possible can anyone tell me how to edit only specific column? I understand using .select but can someone show some examples with some dataset if possible. thank you

My expected output:

```
+---+---+
| id|  v|
+---+---+
|  A|  3|
|  A|  4|
|  A|  5|
|  A|  6|
|  B|  7|
|  B|  8|
|  B|  9|
|  B|  10|
+---+---+
```

Side note: I am new to pyspark so I dont get why need to use 'col'. what is it anyway actually?

Comment: The documentation will help you in a great way! For simplicity, you could start with a `for` loop for the columns. `for colnm, dtyp in df.dtypes:`, and then `if else` would suffice. Once done, you can write it in a short way using a `map()` function

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take note about it.